# refactor method name in eclipse from linked project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have 6 java projects in my Eclipse IDE (juno). One of them is a dummy project which is not meant to be compiled or deployed, it simple holds common logic for the other projects. The other projects use this common project. I edited the classpath of the other projects to include the common source folder as a linked source.

This works fine, but I'm having troubles when I refactor a class or method name in the common project. The refactoring is not propagated to the non-common classes in the other projects that makes use of the refactored class or method, resulting in compile errors that a certain class or method is not found.

The only way I can deal with this is either:

1. Don't change the name of anything
2. Manually change the name in all projects after refactoring

This kind of defeats the purpose of having the common source if a simple edit is not propagated. Is there any way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try eliminating the "common source folder" of the classpath of your other projects, and instead set the common project as a project dependency in eclipse.  To do that, right-click on the project in the project explorer window, choose "properties", then "build path", then the project tab.  Add the common project there.  I know this allows things like finding where methods in the library are called from anywhere in the workspace, and I feel sure refactoring will work that way as well.

Comment: This does indeed work! However, there is a visual difference in the file explorer when you link the source vs adding the project dependency: with the linked source, the common source folder is right beneath the normal source folder (both are under the folder java resources) in the file explorer. With the project dependency, the common source folder is a separate folder (in my case it sits under the build folder). This is kind of a weird place to put external java source files imo.

Comment: I think "external java source file" implies java source that is part of your project but outside the normal tree, and a library project potentially used in multiple other projects doesn't qualify.  I think such a library project should be obviously separate -- in a commercial setting, it would be in a separate source repository, worked on by different people, etc.  Having it separate helps keep it from being modified in ways specific to any one project.  I can understand you being used to one way, but I think this is better.  Anyway, glad this helped.